# How we can build a sharepoint field which is Read-only + visible inside the list setting (similar to the created and created by built-in fields)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, development, read-only

when building a sharepoint list, i always have a requirement to have a field which can not be edited using the list forms + can not be edited using quick edit grid >> so i always set the field as read-only using this PnP script:-

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $clientContext = Get-PnPContext
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $targetField = Get-PnPField -Identity "ApproverFeedbackandnotesPowerBi"
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $targetField.ReadOnlyField = 1
```

but setting a field as read-only will hide the field from the list settings >> which will make managing these read-only fields hard, since they are hidden inside the list settings.. So is there a way to set a field as Read-Only but at the same time to show it inside the list settings (similar to how the built-in fields such as created + createdby work)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, try to edit column settings on UI, as shown below:

[image]